# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /target/test.log

Tags: java, spring, log4j, cxf, apache-camel

Greetings all I am using Apache Camel and Apache CXF in this example:

http://camel.apache.org/better-jms-transport-for-cxf-webservice-using-apache-camel.data/cxfcamelexample.zip

I followed the readme and when tried to run the client & server classes
i got this exception:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /target/test.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:177)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:289)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:163)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:256)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:132)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:96)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:654)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:612)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:509)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:441)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:470)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:122)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:283)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1040)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:838)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:601)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:307)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.example.customerservice.impl.CustomerServiceClient.main(CustomerServiceClient.java:34)
```

so any ideas, how to solve this exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a /target directory at root?  If not, try creating one.  The logger is expecting to be able to create a file in that directory, and if it doesn't exist there's a problem.

Comment: and how to change this path ?

Comment: Not sure - check either the Spring or log4j configuration files.

Comment: change the {active_base} in conf/log4j.properties to the required path.

Comment: doesn't log4j create the necessary directories and files the first time?

Comment: You have to tell it where.  It won't create the directory for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting up a broker, it is possible to have that issue.

I found a bug report in ActiveMQ bug tracking site related with this issue.

Activeio test package inclusion and logging properties:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-1132

I excluded **org.apache.activemq:activeio-core** to remove **test-jar** from dependencies and resolved this issue. That might help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had this issue again, and I would like to reply with what I did which is exactly what @lemiorhan suggested. I'll improve upon his answer by giving sample code. Simply add this after  tag in org.apache.activemq dependency.

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activeio-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```